# Ошибка: Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен

Tags: c#, сокет

Всем привет, скажите почему когда я пишу этот код

```
    class Program
{
    private static Socket sck;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), 4001));
        sck.Listen(4);

        sck.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        sck.EndAccept(result);
        Console.WriteLine("Клиент подключен");
    }
}
```

У меня вылазит такая ошибка:

```
Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен
```

Ошибка возникает в строке:

```
sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), 4001));
```

Причём сразу после запуска...

Answer (score 2):

Неправильный адрес биндишь.
Рабочий код:

```
    public bool Start(int port)
    {
        g_SvSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        var localAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        try
        {
            g_SvSocket.Bind(localAddress);
            g_SvSocket.Listen(4);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            if (se.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.AddressAlreadyInUse)
            {
                Log("! Server : Port " + port + " is busy.");
            }
            Log("! Failed to start server.");
            return false;
        }

        g_SvSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: А если ему не надо, чтобы по любому адресу цеплялись? @Csharp 192.168.0.1 точно принадлежит одному из интерфейсов этого компа?

Comment: Да по идее должен работать биндинг для любого локального адреса. Есть свой код, вот и скопипастил. А этот адрес, вероятно, не локальный.